# Anti-theft code for stereo 04 Honda Accord

Tags: honda, audio, accord

So I pressed and held the 1 & 6 on my stereo in my 04 Honda Accord and got my serial# and put that number and all the other information needed onto this website to get my anti-theft code but when they emailed me the code it has a 0 and a 9 in it. I'm very confused on how I would even put that code in to unlock my stereo. Someone please help me.

Comment: Any up or down buttons?

Comment: its not correct code. Whats your serial? I may can give you code.

Comment: Yeah it's 18001568